# Combine two columns in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

What's the easy way to combine two columns in SparkR? Consider following Spark DF:

```
salary_from  salary_to  position
1500         null       a
null         1300       b
800          1000       c
```

I would like to get combined `salary` column with logic like this. From `salary_from` and `salary_to` take the one that is not null, and if both present, then take a value in the middle.

```
salary_from  salary_to  position  salary
1500         null       a         1500
null         1300       b         1300
800          1000       c         900
```

Is there a way to walk through every line and apply my logic, like I would do with apply method in R?

Comment: I heard about a package combining sparkr and dplyr, sparkrext but i didn't use it yer https://github.com/hoxo-m/SparkRext. Maybe it could help you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` function:

```
withColumn(
  sdf, "salary",
  expr("coalesce((salary_from + salary_to) / 2, salary_from, salary_to)")
)
```

which returns the first not null expression.

Comment: I can't find coalesce in SparkR API reference http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html. Could you please point me out to where I can find more about it?

Comment: You cannot because it is not there yet. Thats why you need `expr` . Otherwise is just a plain SQL `coalesce` so any SQL reference will do. For example http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp. Or PySpark docstrings: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L212

Comment: is there a way to loop through rows of Spark Data Frame?

Comment: Other than fetching a complete structure to driver? No.

Comment: This all sounds to me like SparkR is incomplete and inefficient. Don't you think so? Or maybe I just misunderstand the purposes of it's use.

Comment: It depends on what you expect. Generally speaking SparkR is significantly less mature than the rest of Spark ecosystem and is focused only on specific subset of the API. Regarding iteration it is a feature. I am not sure what you mean by inefficient though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108269/discussion-between-misha-slyusarev-and-zero323).